# HTML Page Designer for creating (easy to use) Tutorials

Tags: html

I am looking for an easy tool to make tutorials (easy as in indesign). This has to be really manageable by our team (3 - 4 people) so that everyone can simply adjust mistakes made in the tutorials. It must support images and be easy to use for our clients.

There is always Indesign to HTML option but we are looking to spend as few time as possible on the development of an actual page, and get started on converting (of our in word - created) tutorials.

Just to be clear: I am looking for a software package that has a minimum of manual work in order to set up a simple page as can be seen on: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

No header, just a sidebar with contents, a search function is also a big plus.

Answer (score 1):

So while I haven't used this myself, it was recommended to me by a former co-worker who specializes in training and curriculum development. She mentioned Indesign but also said:

> ...maybe Adobe Muse (if he wants the content to be accessible online
>   like a webpage). InDesign is a little more difficult to pick up. Muse
>   is literally drag and drop WYSIWYGish.

Hat tip to Sarah Ashton.

Another option would be to use a blogging platform like Squarespace or Wordpress which have their own WYSIWYG editors and templates. This [Squarespace 7 Template Comparison Chart](http://www.usingmyhead.com/squarespace-7-template-comparison-chart/) tells you which themes have a sidebar (not many unless you're OK with the tutorials being blog posts). The [2015 Wordpress theme](https://twentyfifteendemo.wordpress.com/) has the layout you're looking for: side bar but no header.

Comment: Dear BSMP, thanks a bunch.

The software we were looking for was Dr. Explain. It does all that we desire and much more. 

Converts to HTML and .PDF simultaniously. Hope this helps others as well looking for the same thing.

Comment: @Eugenius You can actually add this as an answer and accept it; it's considered OK to answer your own questions and this will make it easier for others looking for the same thing see that this is an answered question. Glad you found a solution to your problem!